# Navigating between two different modules using routing in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 different html pages each having its own ng-app.I want to navigate from one to the other using routing.Is this possible is angular js??
If so,how can it be done??

Comment: add some code , also try using ng-Route

Comment: I am trying it using ng-route but i need to know exactly what needs to be done and whether it is possible to do so.

Comment: try using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902353/angularjs-route-to-another-page-of-different-ng-app-module-after-login

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. Only 1 ng-app can be used in a document. You can however set that one module depends on other, inject it, than use its controllers and views through routing.

An idea is, that you define routing for each outside them (separate module maybe?) and inject that as well into each other. The parent view will have to be generic enough though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a old thread but would like to add answer. Cannot be done by routing but work around is.

Use

```
$window.location.href = "Path to your new page";
```

As a function:

```
self.NavigateToPage = function (path) {
        $window.location.href = rootPath + path;
    }
```

You can also create a directive and use it as mentioned [here](http://conceptf1.blogspot.com/2015/01/angularjs-navigate-on-element-click.html).